# Use only while and assignment to truncate a list of numbers?

Tags: python

I've been asked *(or challenged)* by a friend (just taking some Python course) about this *interesting* question: given a list of numbers, you can only use - 1) while-loop, and 2) assignment to truncation this list and print each step of truncating (starting with first number each time).  In other words, ***no slicing,*** no extra intermediate data structure (eg. copy) allowed.  (*He claimed no one in the class is able to answer it....)*

An example will be easier to understand the strange requirements:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
while ???: 
    <assignment statement>
    <print ??? > 

# expected:
2 3 4 5
3 4 5
4 5
5
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

I kind of *disappoint him* - or surprise him by the end of a few minutes pause.

This is what I share with him, the syntax is called *extend assignment*.   Wonder if there is better/more elegant solution to this.  But this is what I can come up within 3-min...

```py
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> while L:
    f,  *L = L
    #_, *L = L     # another way, since don't care the dropping num
    print(L)

# Output
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5]
[5]
[]
```

Comment: Suggestion: `L = L[1:]`

Comment: Or even just `while L := L[1:]: print(L)`. Requires Python 3.8 or later for walrus operator.

Comment: No *slicing* ... ;-)

Comment: `read_comprehension -= 1`

Comment: One suggestion though that doesn't involve slicing. `_, *L = L`. That first element doesn't need a name.

Comment: You don't allow slicing, but you allow `f, *L =...`, which is slicing?  Your decisions about what is allowed and what isn't are arbitrary.  And by the way, it would be more Pythonic to write `_, *L`, since you don't care about the value.

Comment: Agreed. with *_* var. part, but again the context is to show the *beginner* so I choose to have this redundant one to make it clear. Noted. For slicing part - maybe it's more clear to mention the syntax L[n:] ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying out and got this solution, before I read yours. I think yours is more elegant, haha!

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
while len(L) >0:
    L.pop(0)
    print(L)

[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5]
[5]
[]
```

Comment: Not sure this statement - ```L.pop()``` will meet the requirement?  And ```while L:``` is sufficient too...

Comment: I see, so many roads lead to Rome, haha